# calling a dll function from MS access

Tags: c++, c, vba, dll

hi I'm trying to call this function in **ms access vba**. It just throws up bad calling convention. I tried to recompile access but zilch. I have called **dll** functions before so perhaps I’ve missed something elemental or maybe there is some incompatibility with the **dll** file. thanks in advance for any help.

my ms access code

```
Private Declare Function StartComm Lib "C:\ComConcert.dll" ( _
    ByVal ulPort As Long, ByVal ulBaudRate As Long, ByVal ulByteSize As Long, _
    ByVal ulParity As Long, ByVal ulStopbits As Long, ByVal lncontrol As Long) _
    As Long

Dim OpnPort As Long
OpnPort = StartComm(3, 9600, 7, 0, 0, 0)
```

the original c Code for the **dll file**.

```
DLLEXPORT unsigned long StartComm(unsigned long ulPort, unsigned long ulBaudRate, 
    unsigned long ulByteSize, unsigned long ulPartity, unsigned long ulStopBits,
    unsigned long ulFlowControl);
```

Comment: Apparantly `Long` and `unsigned long` aren't matching types. Try using just `long` without the `unsigned`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Those types match well enough. Since VBA does not have unsigned types you cannot do better. I don't think that the DLL can be changed. So the parameter types are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The function in your DLL does not specify a calling convention. Therefore one assumes it uses the default of `__cdecl`. This means that it is not accessible from VBA. The only way you will be able to call it will be to create an adapter DLL that exports a `__stdcall` function for the VBA to call. The adapter DLL can then forward the call to the original `__cdecl` function.